# SMS automation using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

can anyone please help me to how to automate sending sms query which includes different serial number for different numbers but query structure will be same. can we do that by uploading excel file containing serail number and phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a 3rd party service for that. I recommend [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms)